# Return non-unique entries based on multiple selected columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So say I have a database with the following columns: `song_name`, `artist`, and `album`

In `groupA` I want to pull all of the records and in `groupB` I want to pull all of the records, but only the `song_name` and `artist` columns.

This would give me something like:

```
groupA = Music.select("id, song_name, artist, album").uniq{ |e| [e.song_name, e.artist] }
groupB = Music.select("id, song_name, artist").uniq{ |e| [e.song_name, e.artist] }
```

`groupA` results:

```
  [
      [0] #<Music:0x007fc18a74b348> {
                   :id => "1",
            :song_name => "Angie",
               :artist => "The Rolling Stones",
                :album => "Made In the Shade",
      },
      [1] #<Music:0x007fc18a0e1d90> {
                   :id => "2",
            :song_name => "Beast of Burden",
               :artist => "The Rolling Stones",
                :album => "Some Girls",
      },
      [2] #<Music:0x007fc18a0e14f8> {
                   :id => "3",
            :song_name => "Angie",
               :artist => "The Rolling Stones",
                :album => "Goats Head Soup",
      }
  ]
```

`groupB` results:

```
  [
      [0] #<Music:0x007fc18a74b348> {
                   :id => "1",
            :song_name => "Angie",
               :artist => "The Rolling Stones",
      },
      [1] #<Music:0x007fc18a0e1d90> {
                   :id => "2",
            :song_name => "Beast of Burden",
               :artist => "The Rolling Stones",
      }
  ]
```

What I want to be able to do is delete groupB from groupA and only have the differences remaining. Something like:

`groupA` - `groupB` = `groupC`:

```
  [
      [2] #<Music:0x007fc18a0e14f8> {
                   :id => "3",
            :song_name => "Angie",
               :artist => "The Rolling Stones",
                :album => "Goats Head Soup",
      }
  ]
```

The other big concern is speed, there may be hundreds of thousands of records returned so ideally, the solution would be the least costly method.

Comment: This task actually looks like in can be executed by the database entirely. That's likely faster than any Ruby-based solution. I just fail to understand what data are you trying to fetch, the snippet above should output the same rowsets only with different columns.

Comment: Right, but then I want to be able to cull the results and find out which songs are duplicates, even if those songs are slightly different versions. For instance, perhaps one is the original recording and the other is a remastered version.

Comment: Database itself could do that too.

Comment: I assume you are displaying JSON objects. Correct?  If there were three "Angie's" by the Rolling Stones in `groupA` would you want just the first one removed because the match in `groupB`? I have some suggestions, but first need answers to these two questions.

Comment: @D-side - I'm sure it can, but how?

Comment: @CarySwoveland - It doesn't matter which is removed. I just need to get two separate lists, one list with only one instance of `song_name` per list, and the other with just the duplicates. So in the above example `groupC` is comprised of what was "popped" from `groupA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the no-so-elegant solution for what I was trying to accomplish:

```
artists = Music.select("id, song_name, artist, album").map{|a| [a.id, a.song_name, a.artist, a.album]}

t1 = artists.uniq{ |e| [e[1], e[2], e[3]] }
puts "T1 Count: #{t1.count}"

t2 = t1.uniq{ |e| [e[1], e[2]] }
puts "T2 Count: #{t2.count}"

dups = t1 - t2
puts "dups: #{dups}"

# T1 Count: 3
# T2 Count: 2
# dups: [[3, "Angie", "The Rolling Stones", "Goats Head Soup"]]
```

Comment: I deleted my answer because  I misunderstood the question, thinking Group B was from a different data set. It's clearly stated; I just missed that. As an alternative to array difference, consider making `s2` a set of elements `[h[:song_name],h[:artis]]`, for each `h` in `t2`. Then `t1.reject { |h| s2.include?([h[:song_name],h[:artis]]) }`. I suggest you benchmark that against `t1-t2`. `Array#-` might use the former, but be faster because it's written in C. The approach I suggest might make sense if `t1` is huge, as you could do a roll-your-own file-based `reject`.

Comment: Another thing you could do to save memory, if that's an issue, is to replace each element of my set `s2` with its hash value: `[h[:song_name],h[:artis]].hash`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to do.  You basically want to find duplicate song titles, right?  To do that, you can use SQL:

```
Music.where(song_title: Music.select('song_title').group('artist, song_title').having('count(*) > 1'))
```

However, this would return `Angie` multiple times, and it would include artists who might have the same song title but don't have duplicates, e.g. if The Beatles released a song called Angie but didn't have a duplicate, their song would still appear in the list.  If you just wanted one result that didn't have the same problem as above, you could do something like:

```
Music.where(id: Music.select('max(id) AS id').group('artist, song_title').having('count(*) > 1'))
```

That would return the maximum ID of all of the duplicates found for each song.

A couple of other observations:

Be sure that you have indexed all of the fields needed for the grouping, like `artist` and `song_title`; otherwise, the query will be slow.

Also, a properly normalized database would make this a little better, allowing you to group on `artist_id` instead of grouping on a string value, making it a little faster and less error prone.

#### Edit

You could also do a join to get the best of both worlds (all duplicates without accidental song title collisions:

```
duplicates = Music.select('artist, song_title').group('artist, song_title').having('count(*) > 1')

Music.joins("INNER JOIN (#{duplicates.to_sql}) d ON d.artist = musics.artist AND d.song_title = musics.song_title")
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort here, but it wasn't really yielding what I needed. I came up with a not-so-elegant solution, but it worked.

Comment: How doesn't it yield what you are looking for?  How are the results different?

Comment: When I tested it with my real data set it returned thousands of entries as opposed to the expected 7. I'm not sure why it's different, although I do appreciate that you took the time to answer!